# Проверить какую архитектуру использует приложение

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu, x86-64

Использую Xubuntu 18.04 (64bit). И появилась необходимость узнать какие приложения используют legacy mode а какие Long-mode архитектуры x86-64. Как можно просмотреть такую информацию в терминале(с наиболее полным выводом)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте команду `file _Ваша_программа_`. 
Например:

```
file /bin/bash
```